# how to show the sql lite group by value in android textview?

Tags: android, database, cursor

I created  a sqlite table and I wanted to show the total amount of particular month, Query executed in sqlite it was executed. The problem is, the query which I run it in sqlite the amount doesn't show in android.
Tried a lot, if i run it in sqlite it works.

```
save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Database db1=new Database(getActivity());
        SQLiteDatabase sb1=db1.getReadableDatabase();

//the query which i executed in sqllite

        Cursor cu=sb1.rawQuery("SELECT strftime('%m',daty) as Month,SUM(amount) as Total FROM income WHERE strftime('%Y-%m', daty)=strftime('%Y-%m','now') GROUP BY Month",null);

        cu.moveToFirst();
        for(int i=0;i<cu.getCount();i++)
        {
            tai.setText(cu.getString(0));
        }

        cu.moveToNext();
        cu.close();
    }
});
```

Comment: show the query result

Comment: why are you looping the cursor ?

Comment: it doesn't show any result.it simply display the paricular activity@murtaza hussian

Comment: i removed the loop too,it doesn't work

Comment: is there any record returning from your query ?

Comment: No i just fetch the value alone

Comment: do you know about debugging ?

Comment: yes but it redirect to debug page and wait for a long time nothing did.